# How to create custom tooltip in react-native-responsive-linechart?

Tags: react-native, linechart

I am using `react-native-responsive-linechart` in one of my projects. But the tooltip is not showing properly as the test little bit long and also I can't add a new line. In the official documentation [Link](https://react-native-responsive-linechart.surge.sh/docs/tooltip) there is a process to add a custom tooltip but I couldn't manage to show a proper tootip on top of the point. It will be helpful if someone provides a sample custom tooltip example implemented for `react-native-responsive-linechart`.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you planning to implement with your own tooltip?

Here is an example on how to integrate your own tooltip as an Component.

```
export function OwnToolTip(props) {
  return Tooltip({
    theme: {
      formatter: (v) => v.y.toFixed(2),
    shape: { color: "dodgerblue" }},
    ...props,
  });
```

And as stated in the [docs](https://react-native-responsive-linechart.surge.sh/docs/tooltip#creating-your-own-tooltip) substituted.

```
 <Line tooltipComponent={<OwnToolTip />}
   />
```

I am still new to react native and sure this might be not the best way, so i gladly take constructive criticism.